# Azure WebJob parameter binding cheatsheet

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

Azure WebJobs are so simplify to work with parameter binding, so sometimes it is hard to guess which parameter goes from and to.

For example, `ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger("webjobsqueue")] MyClass input, string Name, [Blob("container/{Name}", FileAccess.Write)] Stream writer)` shows that `Name` is given from a property in `MyClass` which is *automatically* converted from Json string type.

I just copy and use some sense from examples but I don't have concrete knowledge why `Name` is there and how it is binded with previous `MyClass` parameter without any words.

I read several links from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2014/02/18/azure-storage-bindings-part-1-blobs.aspx) and [there](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-get-started/) and even [examples](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-samples/blob/master/BasicSamples/BlobOperations/Functions.cs), but I want to read **whole description of parameter binding rules**. Could you provide a well-documented receipe or cheatsheet about this?

Comment: We are going to provide one soon. Stay tuned :)

Comment: Is that cheatsheet created already?

Comment: @antiocol // not yet. I think I would make it by myself.

Comment: @Youngjae, I have asked because Victor said they were going to provide one "soon"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one cheatsheet (from 2014, so it might be the forthcoming one mentioned in the comments) at http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/2/0/220DE2F1-8AB3-474D-8F8B-C998F7C56B5D/Azure%20WebJobs%20SDK%20Cheat%20Sheet%202014.pdf

Comment: It truly is! Thanks

Comment: The link in this answer is no longer valid.

Comment: As of 2021-05-07, I found a copy here: https://jhaleyfiles2016.blob.core.windows.net/public/Azure%20WebJobs%20SDK%20Cheat%20Sheet%202014.pdf